# Why will my addClass not target only the current element?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, addclass

When I add class `Icon` using the `if` statement it adds it to the correct `h3` but also to any `h3` elements above the correct one, even if the `h3` above is `0`. `Icon` will either be `0` or `1`.

```
        { 
            $('#accordion').append($('<h3>').html(Agency));  
            if (Icon == 1) {
                $('h3') .addClass('Icon');
            }    
            AccordionChild = $('<div>');                                                                        
        }
        AccordionChild.append("<div>").html(ToolsList);
        $('#accordion').append(AccordionChild);
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: $('h3') selects all the h3 tags on your page. Do $('.parent h3') to get h3's inside specific container.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your target `<h3>` is the one appended by the line just above, try this:

```
        { 
            $('#accordion').append($('<h3>').html(Agency));  
            if (Icon == 1) {
                $('#accordion h3').addClass('Icon');
            }
            AccordionChild = $('<div>');                                                                        
        }
        AccordionChild.append("<div>").html(ToolsList);
        $('#accordion').append(AccordionChild);
    });
}
```

More reading here : https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

**EDIT**
To select only one "child" `<h3>`, you have options:

The closest : `$('#accordion').closest("h3").addClass('Icon');`
The first: `$('#accordion').first("h3").addClass('Icon');`
The last: `$('#accordion').last("h3").addClass('Icon');`
The second of the level below: 
`$('#accordion').children("h3").eq(1).addClass('Icon');`

Based on your last comment, the're all on the same level.
You'll have to determine which one has the `icon==1` via conditions...

But when you'll have, you will do something like this:

```
$('#accordion h3').eq(1).addClass('Icon');    // Zero based... So it's the 2nd
$('#accordion h3').eq(3).addClass('Icon');    // 4th
```

And so on.
Or first and last.
;)

***Hint***: Google these keywords : `jQuery` `selector` and a `description of what you want` in your words... You'll find.
While searching, notice those that select a list of elements and wich select only one element. ;)

Comment: Same effect. It adds to all h3s above the targeted one (as well as the targeted one.) this is writing a hide-show by the way. so one h3 followed by a div and so on, all wrapped in #accordion. the h3s below do not get the icon class but are also 0.

Comment: So there is other `h3` below `#accordion`... Ok. Are they on the same level? And is the target on this first level or not? I just read a second time... Plz confirm that you want only the fist level to get the class... And the other ones (on child level) must not have it.

Comment: this is the structure:

'<div #accordion>
    <h3> </h3>
     <div></div>
     <h3> </h3>
     <div></div>
     <h3> </h3>
     <div></div>
      and so on...
</div>'
I only want certain h3s to have the icon based on if icon has a 1, if 0 than no class.

Comment: How to format text in comment : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments/24794#24794

Comment: So what is happening is that the var Icon is receiving a 1 or 0 from a Sharepoint list, then, if it is 1, add icon to the background of h3, if 0 do nothing. Maybe I need to work the other way? and have the h3 determine what to do with the 1 or 0? I tried closest and it gave same result.

Comment: You'll have to know which one it is if you only have one `1`. If there is two `1` for possible 4 `<h3`, you may have to manage to get an array of `1` instead of only one value. This array will fit perfectly with the `.eq()` selector by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Had to write if else... appreciate the input!

> { $('#accordion');
>
> if (Icon == '1') {
>
> ```
>     $('#accordion') .append($(`'<h3>'`) .html(Agency) .addClass('Icon'));
>
>   }
> ```
>
> else  {
>
> ```
>     $('#accordion') .append($(`'<h3>'`) .html(Agency));  
>
>   }
> ```
>
> }